# Broadcast Receiver for Notification or Notification Sound

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, audio

I would like to know if it has how to catch an event, for example: I have a service, this one has a listener (catch notification or catch sound notification) and I need intercept the default sound and change it to another in runtime. I searched many times for this broadcast receiver but I can't find it. If someone can helps me, I appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: What is "the default sound"?

Comment: do you want to change the sound of the notification?

Comment: Default sound of notifications. Yes, I'd like to change it :/